# перестраивание дерева виджетов

Tags: flutter

Хочу задать во многом уточняющий вопрос для себя о дереве. Правильно ли я понимаю что при создании StatefulWidget, при обновлении именно его состояния, все те StatefulWidget'ы которые в нем будут перестраиваться, в то время как StatelessWidget нет. То есть те "ветки-виджеты" StatefulWidget будут перерисованы. Правильное ли это утверждение? Везде пишут подобные слова.... Также меня инересует термин перестройки или rebuild. Это говорит о том что виджеты по факту будут пересозданы? Но в таком случае мое утверждение не верно, ибо в таком случае вероятно должны пересоздаться и StatelessWidget виджеты, если только они не кешируются в некотором роде. Поясните пожалуйста мне момент перестройки дерева виджетов.

Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы понять как происходит обновление виджета, надо узнать из чего состоит его дерево. Когда вы создаете новый виджет вы создаете сразу три связанных объекта дерева для него:

1. Widget — `Describes the configuration for an [Element]` (Widget это описание некоторого Element).
2. Element — `An instantiation of a [Widget] at a particular location in the tree` (Element это некоторое представление виджета в определенном месте дерева).
3. RenderObject — это объект дерева визуализации, то что мы видим в итоге.

На примере данного небольшого кода рассмотрим дерево:

```
Container(
  color: Colors.blue,
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Image.network('https://www.example.com/1.png'),
      Text('A'),
    ],
  ),
);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вы можете заметить `Widget` и `Element` идут один к одному. Но вот `RenderObject` есть не у всех виджетов, так как некоторые виджеты являются делигаторами (например `Container`) для других виджетов. Также надо понимать что `RenderObject` отобразиться/обновится лишь когда `Element` разрешит ему.

Как происходит обновление виджета:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда ваш виджет помечается `dirty` (при `setState` и др.) происходит сравнение нового и старого виджета по `runtimeType` и `key`. Если они не совпадают то все дерево ниже просто отбрасывается и создается новое, если они совпадают, то просто идет замена `Widget` объекта, без изменения `Element`.

Важно прочитать, чтобы разобраться подробнее:

- [Flutter под капотом](https://habr.com/ru/company/surfstudio/blog/501862/)
- [Flutter architectural overview](https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/architectural-overview)
- [Как работает Flutter](https://habr.com/ru/post/476018/)
- [Flutter. Keys! Для чего они?](https://habr.com/ru/post/446050/)
- [Flutter под капотом: Owners](https://habr.com/ru/company/surfstudio/blog/533210/)
- [Flutter под капотом: Binding](https://habr.com/ru/company/surfstudio/blog/512326/)
- [The Stateful Widget Lifecycle](https://medium.com/better-programming/stateful-widget-lifecycle-a01c44dc89b0)

---

Небольшие замечания:

1. Различие между `StatefulWidget` и `StatelessWidget`, в том что у `Stateful` есть `State` и `LifeCycle` в остальном по дереву они идентичны.
2. У каждого `Element` может быть по разному приходить вызов `RenderObject`, но в большинстве случаем он приходит при создании.
3. `Key` могут очень сильно влиять на перебилд виджетов.
4. В дереве виджетов есть множество оптимизаций, чтобы сделать билд быстрым (а в некоторых случаях вообще его не делать если не будет смысла)

Comment: Большое спасибо, за прекрасный ответ. Дело в том что я это читал, даже парочку статей из тех которые вы порекомендовали. Но понимание неполное. Я повторюсь, вопрос больше уточняющий чтобы разложить все до конца по полочкам. Правильно ли я осознал, stateless будут перебилдиваться, но не пересоздаваться(тут const в помощь), а все stateful виджеты, и все  stateful виджеты в их ветках, пересоздадутся?

Comment: И да, и нет. Если до StatelessWidget есть StatefulWidget который вызвал перестроение всего дерева, то StatelessWidget будет создан новый. Но у flutter есть механизм оптимизации с const который вернет предыдущий (а именно тот который мы получили при сборки приложения, все так же как и просто const переменная) StatelessWidget. Я бы рекомендовал использовать const где это возможно и использовать StatefulWidget (или иные способы изменения интерфейса) как можно ближе к концу дерева.